# Virtualbox is losing the benefit of the doubt

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic

We have one user who has started flagging anything with [virtualbox](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) and isn't *clearly* about server-stuff. To them, VirtualBox has lost the benefit of the doubt in the same way that anything with the [linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag seems to hold it. VirtualBox does have some enterprise server usage, but it's uptake is probably well below that of [linux-kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm). Because of its rare usage in what we do, should we:

1. Modify the tag-wiki to clarify on-topic situations
2. Go through the questions we already have in that tag and either migrate them to SU, close as off-topic, or outright delete.

Or should we do something else?

Comment: Sorry if I annoyed you :)

Comment: While I don't think we should be in the business of deciding what makes sense or doesn't in a business environment, I agree that anything tagged with virtualbox deserves the same long, hard, sideways look that most consumer-grade hardware and software questions get.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree that anything tagged "virtualbox" is not server and/or sysadmin-related. For one, VirtualBox does provide a service; it's not an application in-and-of itself. Secondly, it is far more likely to be of use to (and used by SysAds than traditional end-users. (Yes, some Power-Users are going to be playing with it.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not going to look at each of those questions and try to asses whether or not they are "server-stuff" but I will say that while I don't use VirtualBox on a server (nor is it intended to be used that way) I do use it as a valuable tool in my role as a system administrator. I think some may be forgetting that SF isn't just about server stuff.

Because VirtualBox is part of my toolkit I would see questions related to my use of it **in that context** to be completely on topic for SF. Before rashly trying to eliminate all VirtualBox questions consider the context, as well as the content, of the the question. They are not all posted by hobbyists.

Comment: @Starfish, you can disagree all you like but the fact is that **at the time I posted that answer** the VB web site very clearly stated that VB was not intended to be used on server operating systems.

Comment: @Starfish, do you seriously expect people to go back and edit old posts just because something might have changed in the interim? You also appear to have failed to grasp that the reference is in regards to **hosting on** server operating systems, not servers as guests.

Comment: @Starfish, are you serious? Many users have thousands of posts. I doubt any of us have either the time nor the inclination to review everything we've posted in the past. That's just absurd. This is *not* a wiki. Nor is it a forum.

Answer (score 6):

I'm the one that's been flagging them, but not all of them. Many of them are either horrible quality and I've flagged as "Very Low Quality" and others belong on SU since they don't mention servers, server OSes or any other SA related quality. I haven't been blanket-flagging everything. I've been leaving off ones that have legit SA implications - good or bad.

I think that going through the [virtualbox](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox) is a great idea, since I mod-flagged about 30 things in about an hour without even really trying when I was bored this weekend. While useless on SF, I'm sure a lot of them will be useful on SU.

Also, updating the tag wiki would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Have you got some examples of those flagged questions? I agree with John - VBox is a tool for sysadmins. So answers about VBox might help in a server context, too. It`s not much of a difference if I have a Ubuntu guest because I want a Linux client or if I have a CentOS guest because I simulate the PXE boot setup for servers...

Answer (score 2):

Ask the user to stop flagging and let the community decide in the usual way with voting. If the user wants to bring certain questions to the attention of the community then they can drop them in the vote to close room.

Comment: Iain, are you saying that questions that should be migrated shouldn't be mod-flagged. I've mod-flagged plenty of questions that should be migrated before I went on my [tag:virtualbox] spree and they were all marked valid

Comment: @MarkM: If the mod flagging is causing sufficient annoyance then perhaps the flagger should be made aware of other channels is what I'm saying.

Comment: I'm the flagger :)

Comment: @MarkM: drop em in vote to close then ;)

Comment: I think this raises a larger issue, then. Should posts not be flagged if there is already an existing vote-close reason? Is there a msf or mso post that anyone can dig up about proper use of flags?

Comment: @MarkM: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange check the change made on 2011-03-23 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/prevent-off-topic-flags-from-users-who-can-cast-close-votes-but-didnt

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the links.