# Where Should I ask network R&D questions?

Tags: discussion

After reading FAQs I thought It could be related to this site (ServerFault) but got downvoted and put on hold.

Because it's R&D, it falls out of the "production system" requirement. But it's a problem I ran across for my job, using solely existing building blocks (iproute2 & linux 3.10).

My question is (was): [Macvlan based interface pings from host but not from namespace](https://serverfault.com/questions/547361/macvlan-based-interface-pings-from-host-but-not-from-namespace/547624)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I won't speak for any of the people who actually closed your question, but I suspect it had a lot to do with your use of VirtualBox.

There has historically been a lot of [negative feeling toward VirtualBox](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1913/126632) here, much of it motivated by the fact that despite Oracle's claims to the contrary, it is not actually a Type 1 hypervisor and is not considered very well suited to running anything even remotely important.

As a result, questions involving VirtualBox [almost always get a strong negative reaction](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/5529/126632) here.

The remainder of the question seems interesting enough; network namespaces are probably going to be an important tool in the coming years, with so much of what we deploy likely to become containerized.

Comment: Oh ok. That's weird since it's precisely much easier to use in a network dev environment... Next time, i'll say the bulk of the dev is on vmware (which is true) ;)

Comment: I also suspect that if you can reproduce the issue without VirtualBox, e.g. on a nice ESXi host, then nobody will bat an eyelid. Just be sure to mention how you set up your vSwitch...

Comment: My error was to even mention it was virtualized. It's absolutly not related to the problem as I understood later. But thanks for the advice.